# Wakanda RPC client side

Tags: angular, rpc, wakanda

I created a JS file inside the modules folder (backend) in Wakanda Studio (Angular 4 project), I enabled RPC and added it to permissions.waPerm file.

When I check in localhost:8081/rpc-proxy/myRpc/ I can see that the method exists but I don't know how to access it client side since every documentation about it talk about using the Prototyper or GUI Designer of Wakanda studio, but these two doesn't exist anymore in the current version of the studio.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 4 or any client-side framework other than WAF. the JSON-PRC service can be accessed as an external module in your app using HTTP POST.

According to the docs, If you want to call a Wakanda RPC method from any external Page, you  need to add a "script" tag to the HTML page. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rpc-proxy/myRPC?namespace=myRPC"></script>
```

`WAF` and `myRPC` will become available in your angular app. 
Then all you have to do is to consume the namespace myRPC (with a couple tweaks).

Here is what I have done to get it work:

1. Add the script in index.html
2. Then, declare WAF and myRPC in your app.component.ts:

   `declare var myRPC: any;
   declare var WAF: any;`
3. Make the tweak to WAF object:

   `WAF.core = {restConnect:{baseURL : "${window.location.origin}"}};
    WAF.config = {enableFilePackage:true}`
4. Call myRPC using [documented API](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/Calling-Methods-from-the-Client-Side.300-306631.en.html):

   `myRPC.isEmptyAsync({
       'onSuccess': function(result) {
           console.log(result);
       },
       'onError': function(error){ 
           console.log('An error occured: '+error); 
       },

       'params': [4, 5]})`
5. update "proxy.conf.json": with following JSON object:

   `{
       "/rest/*": {
           "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8081",
           "secure": false,
           "ws": true,
           "headers": {
               "host": "127.0.0.1:8081",
               "origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
           }
       },
       "/rpc-proxy/*": {
           "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8081",
           "secure": false,
           "ws": true,
           "headers": {
               "host": "127.0.0.1:8081",
               "origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
           }
       },
       "/rpc/*": {
           "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8081",
           "secure": false,
           "ws": true,
           "headers": {
               "host": "127.0.0.1:8081",
               "origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
           }
       }
   }`

Hope this helps.